# How to a make a sphere out of spheres

Tags: mesh, objects

I know how to make a cube out of cubes or a pyramid out of pyramids, but how do I make a sphere out of spheres?

[image: two example objects in solid mode]
[image: two example objects in wireframe]

Comment: you can use dupliverts

Comment: Of course you can't make a seamless solid with spheres, but you can get the general shape.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Add a sphere and an empty at the center
- Add an *Array Modifier* to the sphere, scale the empty and modify the arrays count.

[image]

- Add another sphere and parent it to the first added sphere <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>
- Enable duplication in the objetcs properties:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: maybe icosphere for this?

Comment: Thanks, but how do I apply the duplicates? Because I would like to do some physics with them

Comment: @FacebFaceb Ctrl-Shift-A (Make Duplicates Real)